# How to fix plaster on ceiling due to screw coming loose?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, ceiling-fan

A builder did a bad job when painting and the ceiling vent came loose, upon inspecting it seems that they broke the ceiling plaster by unscrewing it, tried to hide it by screwing it in another place and now the thing cannot stay in place anymore.

[image]

How can I fix the holes so I can screw the ceiling vent back in place ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a few **pieces of wood** up in the ceiling, to have something for screwing the vent to. The plaster is getting a little worn-out there. I wouldn't trust anchors or make anymore holes for them, nor use toggle bolts; that plaster is about to go and you're about to run out of room (hide-able hole). -I just really don't like wall hangers and I wouldn't want to be pounding some in at that location. It's also not going to be the easiest thing to line up all 3 holes' anchors.

You may get lucky and **rotate it just right** to find something to bite (don't rip the duct) or just get some shims up there and be done with it. If you do rotate it and find undisturbed plaster to screw to, use drywall screws and not the silver ones you probably have from the vent (larger thread; better grab -do not over tighten them).

Judging by the number of holes, this is the fourth time it's come down; shim it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an anchor.   You can't do it right on the edge of the plaster so you might be able to reuse current holes or maybe drill new ones.  Probably an expanding slip plastic anchor (cheapest of the anchor varieties) is the best for something lightweight in plaster.